# Icon Color is not changing in Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For my application, I am in need of right and down arrow for which I'm using CSS Unicode which should be in yellow color for that am using the below sample code. Unfortunately, it's working fine on a desktop web browser and not on a mobile browser where it displays the right arrow color in gray. This issue occurs only in Mobile Chrome Browser.

```css
.closed::before {
  content: "\25b6";
  color: #fe00f2;
}
.open::before {
  content: "\25bc";
  color: #fe00f2;
}
```

```html
<p class="closed">My name is Donald</p>
<p class="open">My name is Donald</p>
```

Please help me in sorting this issue.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me on chrome. A workaround can be to use Font Awesome (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) which provides icons based on a web font. Benefit is that these are scalable and look the same cross-browser / device.

Comment: and place it as absolute position, So it wont change the height of the td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try '**/25BA**' instead of '**/25B6**'.  I think that is the icon that you are looking for.

**HTML:**

```
<p class="closed">My name is Donald</p>
<p class="open">My name is Donald</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.closed::before {
  content: "\25ba";
  color: #fe00f2;
}
.open::before {
  content: "\25bc";
  color: #fe00f2;
}
```

**[Working Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwxGNL)**

**Note:**  I don't know *why* one would work over the other, but Chrome and Safari seem to style that one correctly. Also, the color that you are using in your example is more of a **pink/purple** than a **yellow** (as mentioned in your question), so I continued using the same color as in your example.

I would suggest using a third-party icon library, like [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/), as your previous commenter stated, but that is outside of the scope of your original question.

Comment: `25BA` is a a very thin arrow on Andriod Chrome, more like a dart than a triangle.